# Sorting Multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have problem with sorting multidimensional array with js.It works for second column because it contain number below 10 , but for third column it's not working.

I import this table data into array

```
    <table class="myTable" id="myTable">
        <col class="column-one">
        <col class="column-two">
        <col class="column-three">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Naziv</th>
          <th>Cijena</th>
          <th>Količina</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>gg</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdfs</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>fdsf</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>aaa</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>fd</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>62</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
```

, with

```
var arr = [[], []];
for(i= 1; i<myTable.rows.length; i++)
{
  arr[i-1] = [];
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
        arr[i-1][j] = myTable.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML ;      
  }
}
```

For sorting array i use:

```
arr.sort(mySorting);
function mySorting(a,b) {
  a = a[2];
  b = b[2];
  return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)
}
```

Can anyone explaine what i'm doing wrong and suggest solution that work?

Thanks, Tomislav

Comment: What error/result do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the innerHTML data from the html tags, you get Strings. And when comparing strings, JS sorts them alphabetically, resulting that “10” comes first then “9”.

You have, at least, two possible solutions:

a. force the type to a number, as suggested by dave;

b. let the typecasting do that for you, implicitly, re-writing your compare function as follows:

```
function mySorting(a, b) {
    a = a[2];
    b = b[2];
    return a - b;
}
```

That works because when you subtract one String from another, JS casts the type to Number; and since the sorting function expects a return of LESS THEN 0, 0 or GREAT THEN 0, it works nicely.

obs. for reverse sorting, just reverse the a and b, returning b - a.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
a = a[2];
b = b[2];
```

with

```
a = Number(a[2]);
b = Number(b[2]);
```